# Using a synonym in a make-table query ("select into")

Tags: t-sql, synonym, select-into

I always thought a synonym in T-SQL was just a convenient abbreviation.  Yet when I do the following ...

create synonym BACKUP_TABLE for T_SHORT_NAMES_BACKUP
go

select *
into BACKUP_TABLE
from T_SHORT_NAMES

... I get the error that there is already an object called BACKUP_TABLE.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Synonyms are pointers to other SQL tables.  They are extremely useful depending on what you are wanting to do. You can point them to a table in another database, or a table on another server (through a linked server). We leverage them a lot in our ETLs

The process I use to generate mine:

**Query to build synonyms dynamically**:

```
SELECT 
    'CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[' +TABLE_NAME+ '] FOR [' + 'Put database name here or remove' + '].[dbo].['+TABLE_NAME+']'    
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

From there, you just `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`

Now, to circle back to your question.  You create a synonym for `BACKUP_TABLE` that points to `T_SHORT_NAMES_BACKUP`.

Try:  `SELECT * FROM BACKUP_TABLE`

To find out more about your synonyms: `SELECT name, base_object_name FROM sys.synonyms`

Answer (score 2):

As `select ... into ...` always creates a new table object with the given name there must not exist a object with the same name already.

Simply use your `select ... into ...` standalone, there is no need to add a synonym.

But if you want to add additional rows to your `T_SHORT_NAMES_BACKUP` use `insert into ... select ...` instead:

```
insert into
    T_SHORT_NAMES_BACKUP

select
    *

from
    T_SHORT_NAMES
```

Comment: Okay, this answers my question:  You CAN'T use a synonym in a make-table query.  But I thought SSMS could distinguich between a synonym-object and a table-object.  In any case, I do need a synonym.  There are several queries in the script, each using the name "T_SHORT_NAME_Backup", a name which will change each week.  I don't want to change all the instances of this name.

Comment: Ok, then simply change the order of your statements. First create your backup into a new table with a new object name using `select ... into ...` and afterwards create the synonym for this table object.

Comment: Good answer.  And I guess that's the best I can hope for.  I still have two lines to change each week instead of one, but you can't have it all!